# Accessing data from Axios GET request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm having trouble accessing data from an Axios GET request. I'd like to be able to iterate through all of the data I get and create a table that displays the username, avatar, and score for each user. The only way I'm able to currently render a single username is with the following code:

```
  this.setState({name: res.data[0].username});
```

But the above code only gives me access to the first object in the URL I use in the GET request. If I use this code:

```
this.setState({name: JSON.stringify(res.data)});
```

I'm able to render the entire object as a string. So that makes me think I need to update my render method, but I'm not sure how.

**What steps should I take so that I can map over the state that I'm setting and render each user's data in a table or list?**

```
class LeaderBoard extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  this.state = {
    name: []
          }
  }

componentDidMount(){

axios.get('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent').then(res => 
{

this.setState({name: res.data[0].username});
   }); 

}


render () {

return (
  <div>
    <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>

  </div>
  )
 } 
}


ReactDOM.render(
<LeaderBoard/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, you're just missing a few key pieces.

**Step 1: Add the entire array to your state**

I'm not sure of the exact structure of your data, but you likely want to do this

```
componentDidMount(){

axios.get('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent').then(res => 
{

this.setState({data: res.data});
   }); 

}
```

Now you have all the data you want to work with in your state, ready to be iterated over.

**Step 2: Use `.map()` to create the JSX elements you want**

This code here:

```
render () {

return (
  <div>
    <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
  </div>
  )
 } 
}
```

The big fault here is that it will only ever render **one** thing, because, well, that's all there is. What you want to do is `.map()` through and create a bunch of names from your data, right?

That would look more like this.

```
  render () {
   const namesToRender = this.state.data.map(val => {
     return (
       <h1>val.username</h1>
     )
   })
    return (
      <div>
        {namesToRender}
      </div>
      )
     } 
}
```

All this is saying is "Go through that data and give me the name of each person and wrap it in some `<h1>` tags and spit that out".